# What is the idiomatic, flexible way to specify mutliprocess plan in future?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-future

I just encountered the R packages furrr and future. I would love to use them to write flexible code that will use multiple cores if available on machines running Windows or OSX. I would love for the default # of "available" cores to be something like `parallel::detectCores()-1,` rather than `detectCores().` Seems like `plan(multiprocess)` is the streamlined, idiomatic way to almost do this, but it defaults to using all the cores on the machine. I've encountered more explicit ways to specify the ["plan"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548199/8400969). What is the idiomatic way to use mostly the default behavior of `plan(multiprocess)`, but also limit the number of cores to 1 fewer than whatever `detectCores()` would return?

**EDIT** 
Based on @HernikB 's comment above, I believe that a reasonable answer to this question would be along the lines of `options(future.plan="multiprocess",mc.cores = parallel::detectCores() - 1L)`.

**EDIT**
I am finding that this method frequently doesn't use the multiprocess plan (or at least does not go parallel with `future_map_dfr`) when it seems it could. By contrast

`nc<-detectCores()-1
plan(strategy=multiprocess, workers=nc)`

seems to get it going in parallel. Leaving the question as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `?future::multiprocess`.  You can do:

`plan(multiprocess(workers = 3))`

If you have 4 cores on your compute.r.

Comment: Thanks for that. Does this mean everything that happens in that plan should be used as the argument to "expr" in `multiprocess`?

Comment: Also, this approach should work when I know how many cores are on my computer, but I'm wondering if there is clever functionality (in the same way that `multiprocess` can set up the cluster according to the OS) to set the number of workers still based on what's available, but not as **all** that's available. Thinking about writing code that a collaborator could just pull from git and run.

Comment: Author of future here: Not that `availableCores()` defaults to `parallel::detectCores()`  but will also acknowledge lots of alternative settings that may be in place on the machine where the code runs.  Specifically, if you're on a multi-tenant/multi-user machine, `availableCores()` will make sure your code plays nice on that machine - you should _not_ use `detectCores()` in that cases.   If you want to override the default and still be a good citizen, I recommend settings, say, `options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores() - 1L)` - that will use _at most_ that number of cores.

Comment: @HenrikB forgive me if this doesn't make sense, but it just seemed to me that `plan(multiprocess, workers=7)` returned the following error: `Error in fun(expr = expr, envir = envir, substitute = FALSE, lazy = lazy, : argument "expr" is missing, with no default` while `plan(strategy=multiprocess, workers=7)` worked. It was the error on first attempt that led me to this question.

Comment: @Michael, that's odd - first time I've heard of this.  I can only assume that you have some other package attached that masks one or more of the future functions.  You can test for this with `identical(plan, future::plan)` and `identical(multisession, future::multisession)` - they return TRUE if there's no conflict.  Also, retry in a fresh R session.